# How to Execute multiple select statements in SSIS 2008 using Data flow task

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I am migrating data from one database to another database using SSIS package and i need to write multiple select statements for same table depending on conditions as mentioned below.

**Actual Queries i need to add is**

```
select * from tbldatasets where dataset = 104 and
ADDEDTIMESTAMP BETWEEN 
Convert(datetime, DateAdd(month, -2, Convert(date, GETUTCDATE())))
AND GETUTCDATE()

select * from tbldatasets where dataset = 106 and
ADDEDTIMESTAMP BETWEEN 
Convert(datetime, DateAdd(DAY, -10, Convert(date, GETUTCDATE())))
AND GETUTCDATE() 

select * from tbldatasets where dataset = 107 and
ADDEDTIMESTAMP BETWEEN 
Convert(datetime, DateAdd(MONTH, -1, Convert(date, GETUTCDATE())))
AND GETUTCDATE()
```

**My SSIS package is**

[image]

in the above case only first query is executing. Is there any alternative to write multiple select statements should execute one after another and also
suggest me any tutorial links for SSIS learning.

Comment: You need to clarify what you want to do with the 5 queries you're executing. At the minute it looks like you should be executing a `UNION` for one resultset. However, if you want separate result sets, then you'll need separate OLE DB Source tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this your SQL Statement.

```
select * from tbldatasets where dataset = 104 and
ADDEDTIMESTAMP BETWEEN 
Convert(datetime, DateAdd(month, -2, Convert(date, GETUTCDATE())))
AND GETUTCDATE()
UNION ALL
select * from tbldatasets where dataset = 106 and
ADDEDTIMESTAMP BETWEEN 
Convert(datetime, DateAdd(DAY, -10, Convert(date, GETUTCDATE())))
AND GETUTCDATE() 
UNION ALL
select * from tbldatasets where dataset = 107 and
ADDEDTIMESTAMP BETWEEN 
Convert(datetime, DateAdd(MONTH, -1, Convert(date, GETUTCDATE())))
AND GETUTCDATE()
```

This will combine you data of your seperate queries. for more information read up on TSQL @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

**Update your query by adding UNION ALL after each select statement**

[image]

Comment: Your query works for me perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score -4):

For tutorial you can watch the video series on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cPq9FXk-RA&list=PLNIs-AWhQzcmPg_uV2BZi_KRG4LKs6cRs

For query you have to union your queries into a single resultset.